# Importing JSON or GeoJSON in Google Earth?

Tags: geojson, google-earth, json

I was wondering if it was possible to import layers such as GeoJSON layers on [the web-based version of Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/)?

I didn't find any resources online but for the pro version and only for shapefiles.

Comment: Google Earth Pro certainly doesn't support JSON.

Comment: @nmtoken Yes, but does support shapefiles so that's okay. I can translate gosn files in shapefiles with QGis. My question was rather on the web version

Comment: I'm confused now what the question is, do you want to know how to import data that starts as JSON into a format that can be read by Google earth, or whether Google Earth supports JSON (of any flavour)

Answer (score 2):

You can bring KML files into Google Earth for web, and there are numerous tools to convert from GeoJSON to KML.